# VAR(p) Model Covariances and Moment Equation

Tags: time-series, covariance, matrix, covariance-matrix, vector-autoregression

I'm currently going through the book Analysis of Financial Time Series by Ruey S. Tsay and reached the following statement (The book can be found [here](https://books.google.com/books?id=OKUGARAXKMwC&pg=PA404&lpg=PA404&dq=The+last+property+is+called+the+moment+equations+of+a+VAR(p)+model.+It+is+a+multivariate+version+of+the+Yule%E2%80%93Walker+equation+of+a+univariate+AR(p)+model.+In+terms+of+CCM,+the+moment+equations+become&source=bl&ots=tpezEfttqt&sig=fDRkkB_n2ulCbKt7tNoKkc39gtc&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwipgLjB5fXeAhUFn-AKHcATDbAQ6AEwAHoECAAQAQ#v=onepage&q&f=false), with VAR(1) included in the preview):
[image]

Where:

- $r_t$ is a time series
- ${a_t}$ is a sequence of serially uncorrelated random vectors with mean 0 and covariance matrix $\Sigma$
- $\Phi_j$ are k x k matrices

---

I have been trying to obtain the given bullets by following along with the techniques for VAR(1) provided in the text. There, they do the following for VAR(1):

$$
\widetilde{r}_t=\Phi\widetilde{r}_{t-1}+a_t=\Phi a_{t-1} + \Phi^2 a_{t-2} + \Phi^3 a_{t-3} + ...
$$

So for VAR(p) I tried to follow the same concept:

$$
\widetilde{r}_t=
\Phi_1\widetilde{r}_{t-1}+\Phi_2\widetilde{r}_{t-2}+...+ \Phi_p \widetilde{r}_{t-p}+a_t=
$$
$$
(\Phi_1 a_{t-1} + \Phi_1^2 a_{t-2}+...)+(\Phi_2 a_{t-2} + \Phi_2^2 a_{t-3}+...)+...+(\Phi_p a_{t-p} + \Phi_p^2 a_{t-p-1}+...)+a_t
$$

From there, since $a_t$ is serially uncorrelated, the book states that $Cov(a_t,r_{t-l}) = 0$ for $l > 0$, the first bullet; however, I am unsure of how one thing leads to the other in this case.

Then, for VAR(1) the text states by post-multiplying the expression by $a_t'$, taking the expectation, and using the lack of serial correlations in he $a_t$ processes we obtain that $Cov(r_t, a_t)=\Sigma$, the first bullet.

I am still working out the third one. For VAR(1), it states that by post-multiplying $\widetilde{r}_{r-l}'$ to $\Phi \widetilde{r}_{t-1}+a_t$, taking expectation, and using $Cov(a_t,\widetilde{r}_{i-j})=E(a_t\widetilde{r}_{i-j}'=0$ for $j>0$ yields:

$$
E(\widetilde{r}_{t} \widetilde{r}_{t}') = \Phi E(\widetilde{r}_{t-1} \widetilde{r}_{t})'
$$

and therefore it follows that

$$
\Gamma_l = \Phi \Gamma_{l-1}
$$

and I already have concerns about how that would be a result that comes about for VAR(p) since there's so much more involved in the VAR(p) model.